# Gassfish 3.1.2 with HTTP DIGEST authentication fails occasionally with 401

Tags: glassfish-3, java-ee-6, digest-authentication

Has anyone used Glassfish 3.1.2 with HTTP DIGEST authentication in anger?

I got it to work fine, or so I thought... until I discovered that its behavior was erratic...
it works maybe 9 out of 10 times, but fails to authenticate the 10th time.

This is when I test it with wget as a client on the same machine with the same credentials and the same Java EE application, (as it happens, a REST web service, but I also have the problem on other Applications.) 
I ran wget locally.

My Glassfish machine is only servicing those wget requests, it isn't doing much else!

I've no reason to believe wget is misbehaving occasionally. I calculated the request digest by hand (from the wget HTTP debug) on one of the occasions that it failed, just to be sure. It seemed fine.

When I run wget with debug, I can see it failing first time without credentials, then 
succeeding with credentials. However, 1 time in 10 or thereabouts it fails the 2nd time
 too ( debug shown here.)

```
[writing POST file request.xml ... done]
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 
3.1.2 Java/Sun    Microsystems Inc./1.6)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="jdbc-realm",qop="auth",nonce="1377101691098:d07adb4a1421a265f3aa36bd99df7f6ef8c7a6e7887eb7d876e6b5ce079d1126",
opaque="C26EED99B0A8C0BCA16900215CCD241F"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1069
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 16:14:50 GMT
---response end---
401 Unauthorized
Skipping 1069 bytes of body: [<!DOCTYPE html P...
```

I set debug for javax.enterprise.system.core.security.level=FINE

I didn't see any error messages... but I did notice that for a "good" wget, the "hasResourcePermission" was called 3 times, 2 times returning false and one time returning true.

However, for the "bad" wget call, it is only called 2 times returning false.

> |FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread->2;
>   ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManager;
>   MethodName=hasResourcePermission;|[Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false|#]
>
> |FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-
>   2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManager;
>   MethodName=hasResourcePermission;|[Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false|#]

GOOD CASE ONLY

> |FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-
>   2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManager;
>   MethodName=hasResourcePermission;|[Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: true|#]

Any ideas anyone ? Is there more Debug I could enable ?

thanks

*****************************GLASSFISH DIGEST INSTRUCTIONS*****************

```
 Install a mysql database with yum. 

Follow these instructions (with some changes, this blog is for FORM authentication so stop at step 4)

http://jugojava.blogspot.ie/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html

Create the mysql database "realm_db" with the tables in the above blog

Using the Glassfish console UI, I created a JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Resource for mysql database.

In the Pool Additional Properties, add in your mysql database properties as shown in the blog

On the server-config, Security page, I set "Default Realm" to jdbc-realm

IMPORTANT: When creating the JDBC security realm, use JAAS context of "jdbcDigestRealm" and  JNDI of "jdbc/realm_db". 

I left these fields blank, Digest Algorithm, Encoding, Charset, Password, Encryption Algormithm etc. and I put the passwords in the mysql database in clear text.

By the way, I used an up-to-date version of wget for testing because I read somewhere that older versions don't have proper RFC2617 DIGEST support. The version is 1.14 from Aug 12.
you need a driver file in $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/lib. The file is called mysql-connector-java-3.1.13-bin.jar
```